# Telnet - Why do i have to implement a sleep timer to wait until all data is loaded?

Tags: c#, telnet

Hello in my C# application i have to send and get data from teamSpeak via Telnet.

So I implemented the following function which allows me to send a command and receave the answer via Telnet.

**Initialize Telnet connection with TeamSpeak Server**

```
// Init Steam    
client = new TcpClient(adress, port);
stream = client.GetStream();

// send Password
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("login " + username + " " + password + "\n");
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
data = new Byte[256];
Thread.Sleep(999);

Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
String responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine(responseData);

// send use
Byte[] data2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("use 1\n");
stream.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
data2 = new Byte[9899];
Thread.Sleep(200);

Int32 bytes2 = stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length);
String responseData2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data2, 0, bytes2);
Console.WriteLine(responseData2);
```

**Send command**

```
Byte[] data2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command + "\n");
stream.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
data2 = new Byte[9899];
Thread.Sleep(200);

Int32 bytes2 = stream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length);
String responseData2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data2, 0, bytes2);
Console.WriteLine(responseData2);
```

This implementation works but i had to implement a `Thread.Sleep(200);` (which slows down my application), because elsewhise the data2 Byte[] is empty.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Share your full code, please.

Comment: stream.ReadAsync

Comment: @ThomasChristof With stream.ReadAsync its the same problem.
The data only contains the beginning of the message and i have to implement a timer that the data contains the whole anwser...

Comment: Thats how it works. There is a property, so called, available. If its true, data is available. You have to wait for it. Use an other thread for networking. (So the UI isn't blocked while you are waiting)